# Keyboard-only usage of Google Search

Tags: google-search, keyboard-shortcuts

How can I perform a Google search without using the mouse?

I want to be able to:

- type in the search term and start the search ( possible already since I use a browser search bar );
- navigate through the results ( ideally also between pages );
- open the result page ( bonus points for opening in a new window );

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want a native solution, you could enable the [Google Labs feature](http://www.google.com/experimental/-), Keyboard shortcuts.

Here are the shortcuts you wanted:

- <kbd>/</kbd>: Puts the cursor in the search box.
- <kbd>J</kbd> and <kbd>K</kbd>: Selects the next/previous result.
- <kbd>O</kbd> or <kbd>Enter</kbd>: Opens the selected result.

Comment: Almost there. Any idea why it does not apply to the localized ( i.e. google.ro search ) ? It works if I manually construct the URL but the preference is not applied if I just visit google.ro .

Comment: @Robert: no idea... I guess it's because it's an experimental feature. I would recommend bookmarking the URL that works for now until Google fix it.

Comment: 404 error.......

Answer (score 4):

This is not from Google, but uses Google Search. Try [Keyboardr](http://www.keyboardr.com/)